# How do I upgrade Oh My Zsh when it fails because of a git rebase error?

Tags: git, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I use Oh My Zsh in my terminal and occasionally when I open the terminal I get a request to upgrade Oh My Zsh. When I press Y to upgrade, I receive this error message:

> Updating Oh My Zsh
>   error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
>   error: please commit or stash them.
>   There was an error updating. Try again later?

This is a fairly straightforward problem, but somehow I frequently forget the underlying structure of what's happening. How do I fix it? (asking this question for others who may face it, so I'll answer it myself).

Answer (score 14):

What happened to me, and what probably happened to you, is that I edited a theme file. If that happened, it will cause a conflict when Oh My Zsh tries to update by pulling from origin master. Here's how you fix it:

> $cd .oh-my-zsh/ ( to change to the Oh My Zsh root directory)
>   $git status (this should show you what changes you made)
>   $git stash/git add . (choose whether you want to add and commit the change or just stash)
>   $git commit -m (if you decided to keep and add the changes)
>   $upgrade_oh_my_zsh

The upgrade should now work and you will have the latest version of Oh My Zsh.

Comment: I create my own branch which gets automatically rebased when oh-my-zsh is updated.

Comment: `cd $ZSH` might be more robust  in case you changed the default location

Answer (score 0):

My update was hanging after saying 'rebase successful'. I pressed ctrl+C and ran the command again, and it said 'already up to date'.